# how can i show and hide two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have main activity in which `list fragment` is shown when the app is launched, then there is `floatingbutton` in `list fragment` when that button is clicked it opens next fragment (adding fragment)  and there is again one more button in adding fragment when it is liked then again list fragment is shown in the main activity .

Now I want that when the `floating button` of list fragment is clicked then list fragment should hide and adding fragment should show and when the floating button of adding fragment is clicked then adding fragment should hide and list fragment should show.

How can I do this thing using hide and show a method of fragment class?

how should I call these methods in both fragments when the floating buttons in both fragments are clicked.

Comment: so you just what to hide a fragment not remove it?

Comment: yes I just want to hide one fragment 1 and shoe fragment 2 when the button in fragment 1 is clicked and then hide fragment 2 and show fragment 1 when the button in fragment 2 is clicked

Comment: if you just what to hide it just set the layout inflated by the fragment visibility to gone, this will disable clicks on that fragment as well. If you what to replace fragment_1 with fragment 2 then use fragmentManager to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link and check example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Core-Class/Demonstrationofhidingandshowingfragments.htm

Comment: Link-only answers are rarely desirable on SO. Links may go down or change. Please explain how this helps OP instead of just posting a link.